# C++ - Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'struct ' to 'struct (&)'

Tags: c++, arrays, function, struct, compiler-errors

First of all, I'm a complete C++ newbie. I'm trying to call a function with some arrays of structs (including a 2D one) as arguments and I get the following error:

> No matching function for call to 'function': Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'struct _psoParticle [particleQnty][2]' to '_psoParticle (&)[][2]' for 1st argument

My structs (Let's suppose material = 1 and period = 10):

```
struct unit{
    int inventory[material][period];
    int consumption[material][period];
    int replenishment[material][period];
    int planned[material][period];
    int accPlanned[material][period];
    int demandPull[material][period];
    int costPenalty[material][period];
    bool delivery[material][period];
    int leadtime;
    int inventoryControl[material][period];
    double bufferSize[material][period];
    double bufferLevel[material][period];
    double bufferMgmt[material][period];
    const double lbGamma{-100.0};
    const double ubGamma{100.0};
};

struct _psoParticle{
    double positionBest;
    double velocityBest;
    long pbest;
};
```

Initializing data in main:

```
struct unit CareUnit[2]{};
struct unit centralStore{};
struct _psoParticle psoParticle_CareUnit[10][2];
struct _psoParticle psoParticle_CentralStore[10];
int totalConsumption[material]{}, totalInventory{}, totalLateness{};
int particleQnty{10};
int x[particleQnty]{};
```

Function header:

```
int dbr(_psoParticle (&pso_CareUnit)[][2], _psoParticle (&pso_CentralStore)[],
            int particle, unit (&CareUnit)[], unit &centralStore,
            int (&totalConsumption)[1], int &totalInventory, int &totalLateness);
```

Continuing in main:

```
for (int i = 0; i < particleQnty; ++i)
    x[i] = dbr(psoParticle_CareUnit, psoParticle_CentralStore, i, CareUnit,
           centralStore, totalConsumption, totalInventory, totalLateness);
```

And then the error message pops out.

Any ideas on what I did wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the actual error message?

Comment: @melpomene: No matching function for call to 'function'

Comment: No, the actual, full error message.

Comment: Oh! I didn't see that before! It's 1. Candidate function not viable: requires single argument 'pso_CareUnit', but 8 arguments were provided

Comment: That's still not the full message. And you're missing a [mcve].

Comment: `function` is a terrible name.  Somewhere you have defined it with a single parameter.  I suspect you retyped the function header instead of pasting the actual code.

Comment: There's no need to use a reference parameter for an array, since arrays automatically decay to a pointer.

Comment: This look more like `C` and less like `C++`

Comment: `int totalConsumption[material]{}, totalInventory{}, totalLateness{};`

a) Has a syntax error and b) assuming want to pass an array with three parameters the function declaration does not match, taking arrays of size `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, yes, I know this one.... Well, your function should look like this

```
int dbr(_psoParticle (&pso_CareUnit)[10][2], _psoParticle (&pso_CentralStore)[10],
        int particle, unit (&CareUnit)[2], unit &centralStore,
        int (&totalConsumption)[material], int &totalInventory, int &totalLateness);
```

Note that each argument has full dimensions specified. Now the reason for this is that all your arrays are *static* arrays, so the compiler has to know big it is from the beginning, before your run your program. So that it could do fancy bells and whistles like `sizeof(arr)` and `for(T obj: arr){}` and what not.

Now as you might've noticed, this way of doing things is a mess. You've got a few options to make it better. The minimum-effort one would be to just replace your argument types with templates. like

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, etc...
int dbr(T1 &pso_CareUnit, T2 & pso_CentralStore...
```

Then the compiler will figure out what the hell you're feeding it all by itself. You could also pass em as pointers, then some information would be lost and you'd have to pass along the dimensions somehow, but whatever...

```
int dbr(_psoParticle ** pso_CareUnit, _psoParticle *pso_CentralStore,...
```

You could also use stl types like std::vector

```
int dbr(std::vector<std::vector<_psoParticle>>& pso_CareUnit, std::vector<_psoParticle>& pso_CentralStore,...
```

You could also encapsulate the whole thing like

```
struct Container{
_psoParticle careUnit[10][2];
_psoParticle centralStore[10];
};

int dbr(Container & iContainer...
```

Or even better

```
class Pso{
public:
    int dbr(...
private:
    _psoParticle careUnit[10][2];
    _psoParticle centralStore[10];
    // ... the rest of arguments
};
```

There are also some more funky ways to deal with it, like iterators and whatnot. But in your case I think a simple pointer solution or encapsulation would suffice. Although I'd warn you to refrain from using C-style structs and arrays in the future, they are annoying to deal with and there are all sorts of nice STL containers for that. And that naming convention of yours is super weird, check Google or GNU C++ guide for styling tips.